# Ternary Expression Error in PHP

Tags: php, ternary-operator

My apologies guys, but I've tried everything from adding and removing curly braces to regular closing brackets and I'm genuinely stumped. Many thanks as always!

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in top.php on
line 9****

```
<?php include 'header.php' ?>
    <font color=#EEEED1>
    <form method="POST">
        <p>
            <b>Your Blog Title:</b>
            <input type=text name=btitle value="<?php echo $_POST['btitle'] ?>" ><?php echo $errormsgs[0]; ?><br>
            <center>
                <textarea name=bentry cols="80" rows="20">
                    <?php ($_POST['bentry'] ? echo {$_POST['bentry']} : echo ("What's on your mind?");) ?>
                </textarea><br><br>
            </center>
            <?php echo $errormsgs[1]; ?>
            <input type=radio name=color value="Red" checked><font color="Red"> Red</font><br>
            <input type=radio name=color value="Yellow"><font color="Yellow"> Yellow</font><br>
            <input type=radio name=color value="Blue"><font color="Blue"> Blue</font><br>
            <center>
                <input type=submit value="Create Blog!">
            </center>
        </p>
    </form>
    </font>
<?php include 'footer.php' ?>
```

Comment: How about `<?php echo ($_POST['bentry'] ? {$_POST['bentry']} : ("What's on your mind?");) ?>
` ?

Comment: <?php $_POST['bentry'] ? echo {$_POST['bentry']} : echo ("What's on your mind?"); ?> y ( and ) ?remove brackets and try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest :

```
echo isset($_POST['bentry']) ? $_POST['bentry'] : "What's on your mind?";
```

Comment: Awesome and much appreciated! For some odd reason though in the textbox the default string is shown after many random trailing/beginning spaces hahaha

Comment: That's because anything in the HTML between <textarea> and </textarea> will show up in the textbox. Including the spaces before <?php

Answer (score 2):

To properly do this expression, you should change the line to:

```
<?php echo (isset($_POST['bentry'])) ? $_POST['bentry'] : "What's on your mind?"; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $_POST['bentry'] ? $_POST['bentry'] : "What's on your mind?"
```

Since 5.3 you can shorten it to

```
echo $_POST['bentry'] ?:  "What's on your mind?";
```

**Note:** Neither of these statements actually checks to see if the variable `isset()` or not, but rather if the variable equals true.

If you needed to check where the variable is actually set then you would have to check first then echo:

```
echo isset($_POST['bentry']) ? $_POST['bentry'] : "What's on your mind?"
```